# Tensorflow stack vectors out of loop to create a matrix

Tags: tensorflow, stack, tensor

I have a for loop that creates vectors (tf tensors) of equal length, say

```
a1 = [0, 2, 4 ... ]
a2 = [1, 4, 6 ... ]
...
```

and I want to concatenate these vectors into a matrix, along the 0th axis

```
matrix = [[0,2,4...] , [1,4,6...] ... ]
```

I can do a

```
matrix = tf.concat(0, [matrix, a])
```

inside the for loop. However the first iteration does not work, since matrix does not exist and if I initialize it to a vector, I'm stuck with that vector at the top of the end matrix. Is there a quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack):

```
matrix = tf.stack([a1, a2, ...])
```

Comment: You mean append the a1, a2 to an empty list and call stack on the list?

Comment: Yes, that could be one way to do it.